# Using google maps JS api, how can I open an infowindow where the user clicks on the map? Is that possible?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is it possible to open the infowindow right where the user clicks on the map?

Here's what I have right now:

```
  OnClickMap(event) {
    const map = this.state.map;
    const title = this.props.createNewMarkerTitle;
    const marker = {
      latLng: {
        lat: event.latLng.lat(),
        lng: event.latLng.lng()
      }
    };

    const markerOnMap = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: marker.latLng,
      map: map,
      title: title
    });

    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    const content = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(this.renderCreateNewMarkerInfoWindow(), content);
    infowindow.setContent(content);

    markerOnMap.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, markerOnMap);
    });
  }
```

I'm not sure how I can just click the map, and have the infowindow open on where I clicked.  I tried messing around by removing the marker and just having the infowindow open, but that leads to the window opening in the top left since I am not sure how to pass the latLng to it.

Is this possible?  Otherwise, how can I set up something where:

```
click the map -> 
creates a marker -> 
immediately opens infowindow (instead of having to click the marker to open it)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open an [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) at the location clicked on the map (without a marker), you need to set the `.position` property of the InfoWindow (and don't include the optional `anchor` in the `.open` call).

```
map.addListener('click', function(evt) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  infowindow.setPosition(evt.latLng);
  var content = evt.latLng.toUrlValue(6);
  infowindow.setContent(content);
  infowindow.open(map);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xmowt2kw/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  map.addListener('click', function(evt) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow.setPosition(evt.latLng);
    var content = evt.latLng.toUrlValue(6);
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!   This stuff is pretty frustrating to do using react :( . I appreciate your hlep